# What is the best way to write a part of buffer with quoting?

Tags: c++, sql, buffer, ostream, quoting

For exaplme, I have some buffer : `const char* buf` with next content (mysql packet):

```
72 00 00 00 select * from `db` where (`name` = "Bill's car")
```

and i need to write to ostream only query with quoting. So, result should be next:

```
select * from `db` where (`name` = \"Bill\'s car\")
```

I know, that `<< quote <<` will make quoting and `ostream.write(buf,len)` will write part I need.

But what the best solution for both?

Comment: It's unclear what is being asked here..

Comment: originally, I want to parse mysql client packet to get query

Comment: Can you provide another example?

Comment: Is this coming from an employee of that company that does SQL sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to do:

```
std::copy(buffer + index_of_start_of_sql, buffer + index_of_end_of_sql, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
```

This copies the contents of the buffer character by character to the output stream (in this case `std::cout`). You don't need to worry about handling quotes then.

The only things you need make sure are correct are the two indexes (start and end of chunk of sql).

NOTE: this will print out what is in the buffer, but will not escape the quotes. If you need to escape the quotes, then you'll need to take a different approach. e.g. use `for_each` and a custom functor to check if character is `'` or `"` and escaping as necessary...